# Javascript Regex to match substrings between two Strings but the substrings can contain DOT (.)

Tags: javascript, regex

I do want to match all subbstrings which are between `{{` and `}}`

When this substring does not contain `.` , the regex works fine :

```
"When he come, {{person}} will give his son {{something}}".match(/{{(\w*)}}/g) ;
```

Result :

> ["{{person}}", "{{something}}"]

Now , if this substring contains `.`(dot) , the regex does not work as it is expected :

```
"When he come, {{person.firstname}} will give his son {{something}}".match(/{{(\w*)}}/g) ;
```

Result :

> ["{{something}}"]

#### How to change the regex to be able to mach  also substrings contains DOT , for example here : `person.firstname` . ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or use this pattern to match anything between `{{` and `}}`

```
{{([^}]*)}}
```

explanation:

```
[^}] a character class, anything but "}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`\w` will only match `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _`, cf. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp.

Use this regular expression to include an arbitrary number of points as well:

```
/{{([\w\.]*)}}/g
```